# Different model result stats::arima and dynlm

Tags: r, arima, model, autoregressive

I am calculating an autoregressive model with two different libraries (stats and dynlm). Attached you can find the code and the data. I am using in both libraries the same methodology (least squares). However, I cannot understand why the results are different and why only the interceptor is different.

```
    For an AR(1) 
    Library    |  I      | AR(1)
    stats      |-0.0112  |0.2032
    dynlm      |-0.0089  |0.2032

    For an AR(1) 
    Library    |  I      | AR(1)  | AR(2)  
    stats      |-0.0095  |0.1805  |0.1117 
    dynlm      |-0.0067  |0.1805  |0.1117
```

I would love to get to know from where this difference come from and why it does only accept the interceptor.

```
library(stats)
library(dynlm)

dv <- c(-0.013191321, -0.044640356,  0.010087189, -0.204012882, -0.012571272,
     -0.007839349, -0.052406173,  0.223551008,  0.080406600,  0.033629289,
     0.055427527, -0.088846916, -0.078639196, -0.056276252, -0.089846722,
     -0.102077177, -0.050272578,  0.011440626, -0.008242924,  0.070110962,
     0.040782651, -0.082857752, -0.005299168, -0.084667966,  0.014894776,
     0.055229816,  0.028087332,  0.056620901, -0.036295594, -0.028672407,
     -0.028789346, -0.004536291,  0.019426024)

dv <- ts(dv)

ar.arima <- arima(dv, order = c(1,0,0), method = "CSS") 
summary(ar.arima)
ar.dynlm <- dynlm(dv~L(dv,1), method = "qr")
summary(ar.dynlm)

ar.arima <- arima(dv, order = c(2,0,0), method = "CSS") 
summary(ar.arima)
ar.dynlm <- dynlm(dv~L(dv,1)+L(dv,2) , method = "qr")
summary(ar.dynlm)
```

Attached you can find the answer from Achim Zeileis from the library dynlm:

As for your question regarding the difference in intercepts: The parameterization in stats::arima (that forecast::Arima builds on) actually uses the "mean" and not the "intercept". This becomes clear when reading ?arima and also the argument is called "include.mean" even though the output claims it is the "intercept". The difference in AR(1) is:

```
y_t = int + phi * y_t-1 + eps_t
(y_t - mean) = phi * (y_t-1 - mean) + eps_t
```

The latter can be rewritten as

```
y_t = (mean - phi * mean) + phi * y_t-1 + eps_t
```

So intercept = (1 - phi) * mean.

As an illustration run:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- filter(rnorm(500), 0.7, method = "recursive") + 2
m1 <- dynlm(y ~ L(y))
m2 <- arima(y, order = c(1, 0, 0), method = "CSS")

coef(m1)
coef(m2)
coef(m1)[1] / (1 - coef(m1)[2])
coef(m2)[2] * (1 - coef(m2)[1])
```